# Im getting this error: Uncaught Type Error: Cannot set properties of null

Tags: javascript

Here is the HTML

```
<div id = "calculator">
        <input id = "display"  readonly>
        <div id = "keys">
          <button onclick="appendToDisplay('+')">+</button>      
          <button onclick="appendToDisplay('1')">1</button>
          <button onclick="appendToDisplay('2')">2</button>
          <button onclick="appendToDisplay('3')">3</button>
          <button onclick="appendToDisplay('*')">*</button>
          <button onclick="appendToDisplay('4')">4</button>
          <button onclick="appendToDisplay('5')">5</button>
          <button onclick="appendToDisplay('6')">6</button>
          <button onclick="appendToDisplay('/')">/</button>
          <button onclick="appendToDisplay('7')">7</button>
          <button onclick="appendToDisplay('8')">8</button>
          <button onclick="appendToDisplay('9')">9</button>        
          <button onclick="appendToDisplay('-')">-</button>
          <button onclick="appendToDisplay('.')">-</button>
          <button onclick="clearDisplay()">C</button>
          <button onclick="calculate()">=</button>
        </div>
```

Here is he javascript

```
 var display = document.getElementById("display");
        function appendToDisplay(input){
          display.value = input;
          console.log(input);
        }
```

I tried removing the quotations in the append to display function
I expected it to display each value when i click a button on a calculator

Comment: your code runs without the error you claim - of course, if you have the javascript loading before that HTML it will fail with that error

Comment: That might be the problem thank you for yout ime